# If all $D_v f(P)$s are same, what is it?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

function $f$ is defined around a dot P in n-space. and $f$ is differentiable.
And an arbitrary unit vector $\mathbf{v}$
if directional differential coefficients($D_\mathbf{v}f(P)$) are all same, what is that? And how can I show that?

Comment: What do you mean by "what is it"? This only gives you *local* behavior of $f$ near $P$, but does not critique the *global* behavior of $f$ (further away from $P$).

Comment: If you mean that $D_v f(P) = D_w f(P)$ for all unit tangent vectors $v$ and $w$, try setting $w=-v$...

Comment: Sorry for my coarse question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $f:\>{\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}$ is differentiable at ${\bf p}$ then there is a vector ${\bf a}$, called the *gradient* $\nabla f({\bf p})$, such that
$$f({\bf p}+{\bf X})-f({\bf p})={\bf a}\cdot{\bf X}+o\bigl(|{\bf X}|\bigr)\qquad({\bf X}\to{\bf 0})\ .\tag{1}$$
Let ${\bf X}:=t{\bf U}$ with $t>0$ and ${\bf U}$ a unit vector. Then from $(1)$ it follows that
$${f({\bf p}+t{\bf U})-f({\bf p})\over t}={\bf a}\cdot{\bf U}+o(1)\qquad(t\to 0+)\ ,$$
and this in turn is saying that
$$D_{\bf U}f({\bf p})={\bf a}\cdot{\bf U}\ .$$
Here the right hand side is independent of ${\bf U}\in S^{n-1}$ only if ${\bf a}={\bf 0}$, which means that $\nabla f({\bf p})={\bf 0}$, i.e., that ${\bf p}$ is a critical point of $f$.